# delete mysite application from sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016, mysite

We have a dev environment which has a very broken mysite application. We want to delete all the personal mysites in it (not many there), delete the related database and the actual mysite application as well and start again from scratch.
Is there a simple step through anywhere on how to do this? Or could someone let me know what is the best process to follow.
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open **Central Administration > Application Management > Manage web applications**. Select correct web application and click **Delete** in the ribbon.

[image]

This action will delete:

- Content database(s) connected to the web application and all personal sites
- Web site from IIS